# Get the properties from an certificate stored as file

Tags: javascript, certificate

I want to show a certificate uploaded on my webserver on my website. I thought about displaying to who it was issued and until it is valid. In Windows I can simply double click on it to see all details and properties but how can I achieve this with javascript? Is this even possible? This is just the public key so it isn't protected by a password.

Let's say the path to the certificate is `/certs/TestCert.cer`
This is some dummy code I figured out in a moment to show my goal briefly

```
function displayCertInfo(path) {
    // get properties here
    $issuedTo = /* get issued to property of the cert stored at path */
    $validUntil = /* get valid until property of the cert stored at path */
    document.write("Issued to " + $issuedTo)
    document.write("Valid until " + $validUntil)
}

displayCertInfo("/certs/TestCert.cer")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The certificate is encoded using ASN.1 notation in a DER binary file or in a PEM file encoded in base 64. A `.crt` file can be DER encoded or PEM encoded

You need to use a cryptographic library like [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/README.md) or [pkijs](https://pkijs.org) to decode the certificate content. This is an example with forge

```
 var cert = pki.certificateFromPem(pem);
 console.log(cert.validity.notAfter);
```

Comment: In the time since, would you happen to know of a lighter library? I'm looking to just parse that data, not using the cert itself. Thank you!